# Convert YUV webcam image to java byte array

Tags: java, arrays, performance, bufferedimage, yuv

In Java, what is the most efficient way of converting a frame of PC webcam image data in YUV (I420 or YUY2) format to a byte (or integer) array?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about java, but this is how you can solve it using ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -o out.yuv
```

Converts any input to 420 planar yuv.

Comment: I already have the data in memory in the right 'format' if only it were called a byte array instead of an image buffer. Converting it to RGB and back to data array is possible but not efficient. I'm guessing that ffmpeg approach takes it through an even more demanding route. It's possible that "in.avi -vcodec" cuts out the "createRealizedPlayer" which might save time, but I still would know how to access the camera in Java with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this project:

http://code.google.com/p/java-yuv/

I believe it has some code you can use

Comment: You may be right but I've looked at this before and can't see how to use it. I've got the data from the camera using "createRealizedPlayer" and "grabFrame". I've no objection to using a streaming approach as if reading a file (assuming it's reasonable efficient) but I don't know how to set up a camera this way. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.  It may not be the MOST efficient, but PixelGrabber class seems to work with what I think is just a block data copy.  Having said that, I'll still be happy to hear any more efficient methods.
Thanks for your suggestions.